# Tokenize nested expression but ignore quoted string with spaces

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am looking to pretty print the following string

```
r"file='//usr/env/0/test/0', name='test', msg=Test.Msg(type=String, bytes_=Bytes(value=b\" 0\x80\x00\x00y\x17\`\"))"
```

to

```
    file='//usr/env/0/test/0',
    name='test',
    msg=Test.Msg(
        type=String,
        bytes=Bytes(
            value=b\" 0\x80\x00\x00y\x17\`\""
        )
    )
```

To start off, I tried using pyparsing to tokenize the input

```py
from pyparsing import *
content = r"(file='//usr/env/0/test/0', name='test', msg=Test.Msg(type=String, bytes_=Bytes(value=b\" 0\x80\x00\x00y\x17\`\")))"
expr     = nestedExpr( '(', ')', ignoreExpr=None)
result = expr.parseString(content)
result.pprint()
```

This gives me a nested list but the Byte array gets split up on whitespace

```
[["file='//usr/env/0/test/0',",
  "name='test',",
  'msg=Test.Msg',
  ['type=String,',
   'bytes_=Bytes',
   ['value=b\\"', '0\\x80\\x00\\x00y\\x17\\`\\"']]]]
```

Anyone know how I can delimit on comma to return the following instead?

```
[["file='//usr/env/0/test/0',",
  "name='test',",
  'msg=Test.Msg',
  ['type=String,',
   'bytes_=Bytes',
   ['value=b\\" 0\\x80\\x00\\x00y\\x17\\`\\"']]]]
```

Comment: How did you get that input string? Isn't the `bytes` quoting invalid, I mean shouldn't it be `r"""...(value=b" 0\x80\x00\x00y\x17\`"))"""`?

Comment: The string is a dump of an object, that's why the byte array is escaped.

Comment: Ah, then the dump is wrong. Backslashes in a raw string are literal, though they prevent a syntax error at least. If it's supposed to escape quotes it should give you a triple-quoted string like I wrote.

Comment: Okay but this is what I get currently. Anyway the triple-quoted string still does not help with the segmented byte array, due to white space.

Comment: Oh, you're right, yeah I'm missing the point.

Comment: Since the string is valid Python, you could use [`tokenize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) to parse it, but then I'm not sure how to pretty-print it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the desired results, we need to define a content expression for the contents of your nested expression. The default contents is a any quoted string or space-delimited word. But I think your content is more like a comma-separated list.

Pyparsing defines a comma_separated_list expression in pyparsing_common, but it won't work here because it doesn't understand that the `()`s for the nested expression should not be part of the items in the comma-separated list. So we have to write a slightly modified version:

```
from pyparsing import *
content = r"""(file='//usr/env/0/test/0', name='test', msg=Test.Msg(type=String, bytes_=Bytes(value=b" 0\x80\x00\x00y\x17\`")))"""

# slightly modified comma_separated_list from pyparsing_common
commasepitem = (
        Combine(
            OneOrMore(
                ~Literal(",")
                + Word(printables, excludeChars="(),")
                + Optional(White(" ") + ~FollowedBy(oneOf(", ( )")))
            )
        )
    )
comma_separated_list = delimitedList(quotedString() | commasepitem)

expr     = nestedExpr( '(', ')', content=comma_separated_list)

result = expr.parseString(content)
result.pprint(width=60)

print(result.asList() == 
        [["file='//usr/env/0/test/0'",
          "name='test'",
          'msg=Test.Msg',
          ['type=String',
           'bytes_=Bytes',
           ['value=b" 0\\x80\\x00\\x00y\\x17\\`"']]]])
```

prints:

```
[["file='//usr/env/0/test/0'",
  "name='test'",
  'msg=Test.Msg',
  ['type=String',
   'bytes_=Bytes',
   ['value=b" 0\\x80\\x00\\x00y\\x17\\`"']]]]
True
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect!